# Extract lines between two sentence in a file

Tags: python, file

I have a file that contains these informations

```
number of atoms
   2
Atom labels, atom number, coords (Angstrom)
H    1    0.00000000    0.00000000    0.00000000
H    1    0.00000000    0.00000000    0.74080000
Overall charge
   0
Number of basis funcs
   2
Maximum number of primitives
```

I want to extract the lines between the line that starts with "Atom"  and line starts with "Overall"
I tried with code below, but instead of getting

```
H    1    0.00000000    0.00000000    0.00000000
H    1    0.00000000    0.00000000    0.74080000
```

I got an empty file without any lines.

```
infile = open('h2_sample.input','r')
ouput = open('coordinate.txt','w')
copy = False
coordinate = []
for line in infile:
    if line.strip() == "(Angstrom)":
        copy = True
        coordinate = []  
    elif line.strip() == 'Overall':
        copy = False 
        for strings in coordinate:
            output.write(strings + '\n')
    elif copy:
        coordinate.append(line.strip())
```

What do u think, I did wrong ?

Comment: I believe you meant `if "(Angstrom)" in line:`.  The line after being stripped will not equal "(Angstrom)", but it will contain it.  Same with "Overall".

Comment: I would use a multi-line regex negative look-behind and ahead, or just match lines with "^H\t" (spaces) in case.  I don't know the latter works in general.

Comment: I tried with regex, and it worked, but they extract the lines as a list and I don't want that as I am going to use these lines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Read all the lines of the file
2. Find the lines you want to keep
3. Write to output file

```
with open("h2_sample.input.txt") as infile:
    lines = infile.read().splitlines()
    
start = [i for i, line in enumerate(lines) if line.startswith("Atom ")][0]
end = [i for i, line in enumerate(lines) if line.startswith("Overall")][0]

with open("coordinate.txt", "w") as outfile:
    outfile.write("\n".join(lines[start+1:end]))
```

###### Output:

coordinate.txt:

```
H    1    0.00000000    0.00000000    0.00000000
H    1    0.00000000    0.00000000    0.74080000
```

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:** As replies have pointed out, you're likely attempting to check if your strings are *in* the line. This is also a valid approach, I've edited the code block to do this. (My original answer is also below.)

---

In Python, `string.strip()` will remove leading and trailing whitespace, not return the first or last word (as you're using it). You also need to use `output.close()` and call `.readlines()` on `infile` to turn it into an array of lines.

---

```py
infile = open('h2_sample.input', 'r').readlines()
ouput = open('coordinate.txt', 'w')
copy = False
coordinate = []
for line in infile:
    if '(Angstrom)' in line:
        copy = True
        coordinate = []
    elif 'Overall' in line:
        copy = False
        for strings in coordinate:
            output.write(strings + '\n')
    elif copy:
        coordinate.append(line)

output.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

First. You should use context manager because you are not closing files "infile" and "ouput" or use at the end infile.close() and ouput.close() Try:

```
with open('h2_sample.input','r') as infile, open('coordinate.txt','w') as ouput:
```

Then in indent write lines.
Line `if line.strip() == "(Angstrom)":` checks if line is equal `(Angstrom)`. You should use:

```
if "(Angstrom)" in line.strip():
```

It will return True if "Angstrom" is in line. The same goes for the first elif statement.